# Problems with BSplineFunction vs. BSplineSurface

Tags: functions, graphics3d, splines

Why are those surfaces different?

```
cpts = Table[{x, y, RandomReal[{0, 2}]}, {x, 0, 7}, {y, 0, 5}];
surf = BSplineSurface[cpts];
surfFn = BSplineFunction[cpts];


Show[
 Plot3D[surfFn[x/7, y/5][[3]], {x, 0, 7}, {y, 0, 5}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Red,          
                                              BoundaryStyle -> Red, BaseStyle -> Thick],
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Blue, Thick}], surf}], 
 Background -> GrayLevel@.7]
```

[image]

Comment: Right. More clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BSplineFunction[{{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}, "<>"]` is a map from parametric space to "plotting" space, *i.e.* $\mathrm{BSplineFunction}:(u,v)\mapsto (x,y,z)$, so instead of `Plot3D[surfFn[x/7, y/5][[3]], {x, 0, 7}, {y, 0, 5}]`, it should be written as `ParametricPlot3D[surfFn[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]`.

```
cpts = Table[{x, y, RandomReal[{0, 2}]}, {x, 0, 7}, {y, 0, 5}];
surf = BSplineSurface[cpts];
surfFn = BSplineFunction[cpts];

Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[surfFn[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
        Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Red, BoundaryStyle -> Red, 
        BaseStyle -> Thick],
    Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Blue, Thick}], surf}],
    Background -> GrayLevel@.7]
```